# SELECT * duplicating results of table, but selecting each field does not

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, ssms, ibm-midrange

My office runs an AS400 server, which I query regularly for daily tasks. We have a data file of 200 row that's giving us an issue I've never seen before.

When running the query below in SSMS, it yields 400 rows (duplicating each row in file) but also refuses to sort the results under any form of "order by" clause. When running the same SQL inside the AS400, it returns what you'd expect, 200 rows that can be sorted however you'd like.

```
execute('
select * from lib.file
') at as400
```

That's not even the strangest part in my opinion. When querying the same file, but explicitly stating each and every field (ex: select field1, field2, ...) SSMS returns the 200 rows and lets me sort however I'd like.

Has anyone seen behavior like this? What is the difference in execution between SELECT * and SELECT (all fields)?

Comment: There is no difference in the number of rows returned.  Something else is going on.

Comment: With `EXEC ... AT`, SQL Server is at the mercy of whatever the remote server and the database driver produce when the query is passed through. SSMS is almost certainly a red herring in any case; it's merely a front-end. You may try the same thing in `sqlcmd` to confirm.

Comment: are you sure `as400` linked server is pointing to the same server you run the query directly in? to me that would be the only thing

Comment: yeah, something else is going on.  What are you doing in SSMS after the `execute( ) at ...`

Comment: @eshirvana yes I am positive it's pointing directly to the same server. I've used SSMS to query our AS400 for 2 years now without any kind of hiccups.

Comment: @Charles I am not doing anything after the execute statement. The SSMS UI is much easier to view results than the AS400, so that's why I use it this way.